# Static file not found in Django production

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-deployment

I am trying to deploy my Django project using Ubuntu and apache webserver. When I transferred my project to the Ubuntu web server and tested it in development, everything went fine. However when changed to production, I experienced file not found problem and I suspect this problem is related to my setings.py, but I am unable to troubleshoot it further. The error I see in production when accessing my site is:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://139.162.163.35/

Django Version: 3.1.3
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jianwu/HD_website/website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/jianwu/HD_website/website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/jianwu/HD_website/website/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 63, in view
    self = cls(**initkwargs)
  File "/home/jianwu/HD_website/website/index/views.py", line 57, in __init__
    self.ContextObject.importTextFile('static/mainAboutUs.txt')
  File "/home/jianwu/HD_website/website/index/views.py", line 50, in importTextFile
    with open(filePath,'r') as fid:

Exception Type: FileNotFoundError at /
Exception Value: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'static/mainAboutUs.txt'
```

In my Meta I have

```
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT   
'/var/www/html'
CONTEXT_PREFIX  
''
CSRF_COOKIE 
'jF3vdEgpyhbKxavRw3pEWzRdIjc4lvw0MsV4lpBLdYXPqcGcIVyH02kEuBeGSXlh'
DOCUMENT_ROOT   
'/var/www/html'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   
'CGI/1.1'
HTTP_ACCEPT 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
'gzip, deflate'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
'da-DK,da;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,bg;q=0.6,zh-CN;q=0.5,zh;q=0.4'
HTTP_CONNECTION 
'keep-alive'
HTTP_COOKIE 
'csrftoken=jF3vdEgpyhbKxavRw3pEWzRdIjc4lvw0MsV4lpBLdYXPqcGcIVyH02kEuBeGSXlh'
HTTP_HOST   
'139.162.163.35'
HTTP_PURPOSE    
'prefetch'
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS  
'1'
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, '
 'like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.192 Safari/537.36')
PATH_INFO   
'/'
PATH_TRANSLATED 
'/home/jianwu/HD_website/website/website/wsgi.py/'
QUERY_STRING    
''
REMOTE_ADDR 
'94.147.65.45'
REMOTE_PORT 
'58717'
REQUEST_METHOD  
'GET'
REQUEST_SCHEME  
'http'
REQUEST_URI 
'/'
SCRIPT_FILENAME 
'/home/jianwu/HD_website/website/website/wsgi.py'
SCRIPT_NAME 
''
SERVER_ADDR 
'139.162.163.35'
SERVER_ADMIN    
'webmaster@localhost'
SERVER_NAME 
'139.162.163.35'
SERVER_PORT 
'80'
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SIGNATURE    
'********************'
SERVER_SOFTWARE 
'Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)'
apache.version  
(2, 4, 41)
mod_wsgi.application_group  
'139.162.163.35|'
mod_wsgi.callable_object    
'application'
mod_wsgi.daemon_connects    
'1'
mod_wsgi.daemon_restarts    
'0'
mod_wsgi.daemon_start   
'1615618126945298'
mod_wsgi.enable_sendfile    
'0'
mod_wsgi.handler_script 
''
mod_wsgi.ignore_activity    
'0'
mod_wsgi.listener_host  
''
mod_wsgi.listener_port  
'80'
mod_wsgi.path_info  
'/'
mod_wsgi.process_group  
'django_app'
mod_wsgi.queue_start    
'1615618126945099'
mod_wsgi.request_handler    
'wsgi-script'
mod_wsgi.request_id 
'Z5qMaD13cW8'
mod_wsgi.request_start  
'1615618126944871'
mod_wsgi.script_name    
''
mod_wsgi.script_reloading   
'1'
mod_wsgi.script_start   
'1615618126945462'
mod_wsgi.thread_id  
2
mod_wsgi.thread_requests    
13
mod_wsgi.total_requests 
27
mod_wsgi.version    
(4, 6, 8)
wsgi.errors 
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<wsgi.errors>' encoding='utf-8'>
wsgi.file_wrapper   
<class 'mod_wsgi.FileWrapper'>
wsgi.input  
<mod_wsgi.Input object at 0x7f38645595e0>
wsgi.input_terminated   
True
wsgi.multiprocess   
False
wsgi.multithread    
True
wsgi.run_once   
False
wsgi.url_scheme 
'http'
wsgi.version    
(1, 0)
```

In settings in the webrowser I have

```
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  
{}
ADMINS  
[]
ALLOWED_HOSTS   
['139.162.163.35']
APPEND_SLASH    
True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS 
['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS    
'********************'
AUTH_USER_MODEL 
'auth.User'
BASE_DIR    
PosixPath('/home/jianwu/HD_website/website')
CACHES  
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  
'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX 
'********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    
600
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE 
31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    
'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE    
'Lax'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   
'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME    
'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS    
[]
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS   
False
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
             'HOST': '',
             'NAME': PosixPath('/home/jianwu/HD_website/website/db.sqlite3'),
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIGRATE': True,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': ''}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS    
[]
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS   
1000
DATETIME_FORMAT 
'N j, Y, P'
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M']
DATE_FORMAT 
'N j, Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y',
 '%b %d %Y',
 '%b %d, %Y',
 '%d %b %Y',
 '%d %b, %Y',
 '%B %d %Y',
 '%B %d, %Y',
 '%d %B %Y',
 '%d %B, %Y']
DEBUG   
True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  
False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   
'.'
DEFAULT_CHARSET 
'utf-8'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER  
'django.views.debug.ExceptionReporter'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER   
'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    
'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  
'webmaster@localhost'
DEFAULT_HASHING_ALGORITHM   
'sha256'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    
''
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  
''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  
[]
EMAIL_BACKEND   
'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST  
'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD 
'********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER 
''
EMAIL_PORT  
25
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE  
None
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE   
'********************'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    
'[Django] '
EMAIL_TIMEOUT   
None
EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME 
False
EMAIL_USE_SSL   
False
EMAIL_USE_TLS   
False
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS   
None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    
['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS 
420
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    
None
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   
0
FIXTURE_DIRS    
[]
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   
None
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  
None
FORM_RENDERER   
'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS  
[]
INSTALLED_APPS  
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
INTERNAL_IPS    
[]
LANGUAGES   
[('af', 'Afrikaans'),
 ('ar', 'Arabic'),
 ('ar-dz', 'Algerian Arabic'),
 ('ast', 'Asturian'),
 ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
 ('bg', 'Bulgarian'),
 ('be', 'Belarusian'),
 ('bn', 'Bengali'),
 ('br', 'Breton'),
 ('bs', 'Bosnian'),
 ('ca', 'Catalan'),
 ('cs', 'Czech'),
 ('cy', 'Welsh'),
 ('da', 'Danish'),
 ('de', 'German'),
 ('dsb', 'Lower Sorbian'),
 ('el', 'Greek'),
 ('en', 'English'),
 ('en-au', 'Australian English'),
 ('en-gb', 'British English'),
 ('eo', 'Esperanto'),
 ('es', 'Spanish'),
 ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'),
 ('es-co', 'Colombian Spanish'),
 ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'),
 ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'),
 ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'),
 ('et', 'Estonian'),
 ('eu', 'Basque'),
 ('fa', 'Persian'),
 ('fi', 'Finnish'),
 ('fr', 'French'),
 ('fy', 'Frisian'),
 ('ga', 'Irish'),
 ('gd', 'Scottish Gaelic'),
 ('gl', 'Galician'),
 ('he', 'Hebrew'),
 ('hi', 'Hindi'),
 ('hr', 'Croatian'),
 ('hsb', 'Upper Sorbian'),
 ('hu', 'Hungarian'),
 ('hy', 'Armenian'),
 ('ia', 'Interlingua'),
 ('id', 'Indonesian'),
 ('ig', 'Igbo'),
 ('io', 'Ido'),
 ('is', 'Icelandic'),
 ('it', 'Italian'),
 ('ja', 'Japanese'),
 ('ka', 'Georgian'),
 ('kab', 'Kabyle'),
 ('kk', 'Kazakh'),
 ('km', 'Khmer'),
 ('kn', 'Kannada'),
 ('ko', 'Korean'),
 ('ky', 'Kyrgyz'),
 ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'),
 ('lt', 'Lithuanian'),
 ('lv', 'Latvian'),
 ('mk', 'Macedonian'),
 ('ml', 'Malayalam'),
 ('mn', 'Mongolian'),
 ('mr', 'Marathi'),
 ('my', 'Burmese'),
 ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmål'),
 ('ne', 'Nepali'),
 ('nl', 'Dutch'),
 ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'),
 ('os', 'Ossetic'),
 ('pa', 'Punjabi'),
 ('pl', 'Polish'),
 ('pt', 'Portuguese'),
 ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'),
 ('ro', 'Romanian'),
 ('ru', 'Russian'),
 ('sk', 'Slovak'),
 ('sl', 'Slovenian'),
 ('sq', 'Albanian'),
 ('sr', 'Serbian'),
 ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'),
 ('sv', 'Swedish'),
 ('sw', 'Swahili'),
 ('ta', 'Tamil'),
 ('te', 'Telugu'),
 ('tg', 'Tajik'),
 ('th', 'Thai'),
 ('tk', 'Turkmen'),
 ('tr', 'Turkish'),
 ('tt', 'Tatar'),
 ('udm', 'Udmurt'),
 ('uk', 'Ukrainian'),
 ('ur', 'Urdu'),
 ('uz', 'Uzbek'),
 ('vi', 'Vietnamese'),
 ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese')]
LANGUAGES_BIDI  
['he', 'ar', 'ar-dz', 'fa', 'ur']
LANGUAGE_CODE   
'en-us'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE 
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_HTTPONLY    
False
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    
'django_language'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH    
'/'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SAMESITE    
None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_SECURE  
False
LOCALE_PATHS    
[]
LOGGING 
{}
LOGGING_CONFIG  
'logging.config.dictConfig'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  
'/accounts/profile/'
LOGIN_URL   
'/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL 
None
MANAGERS    
[]
MEDIA_ROOT  
''
MEDIA_URL   
'/'
MESSAGE_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
MIDDLEWARE  
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
MIGRATION_MODULES   
{}
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    
'F j'
NUMBER_GROUPING 
0
PASSWORD_HASHERS    
'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT  
'********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS 
'********************'
PREPEND_WWW 
False
ROOT_URLCONF    
'website.urls'
SECRET_KEY  
'********************'
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER   
False
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF 
True
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS  
False
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD 
False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS 
0
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER 
None
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT  
[]
SECURE_REFERRER_POLICY  
'same-origin'
SECURE_SSL_HOST 
None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT 
False
SERVER_EMAIL    
'root@localhost'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS 
'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  
1209600
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   
None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME 
'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH 
'/'
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE 
'Lax'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   
False
SESSION_ENGINE  
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE 
False
SESSION_FILE_PATH   
None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  
False
SESSION_SERIALIZER  
'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
SETTINGS_MODULE 
'website.settings'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y P'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y'
SIGNING_BACKEND 
'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS  
[]
STATICFILES_DIRS    
('/home/jianwu/HD_website/website/static',)
STATICFILES_FINDERS 
['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
STATICFILES_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT 
'/home/jianwu/HD_website/website/productionStatic'
STATIC_URL  
'/static/'
TEMPLATES   
[{'APP_DIRS': True,
  'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
  'DIRS': ['templates'],
  'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug',
                                     'django.template.context_processors.request',
                                     'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                                     'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS    
[]
TEST_RUNNER 
'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
','
TIME_FORMAT 
'P'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
TIME_ZONE   
'UTC'
USE_I18N    
True
USE_L10N    
True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
False
USE_TZ  
True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST    
False
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT    
False
WSGI_APPLICATION    
'website.wsgi.application'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS 
'DENY'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   
'F Y'
```

My settings.py is as below and I have pointed my `STATIC_ROOT` to `productionStatic` folder. This is the folder where collectstatic has transferred the static files from my `static` folder to `productionStatic`. I am not sure why this is necessary as I can only read from Django's documentation that the files should be copied over in production.

```
"""
Django settings for website project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os
import json

#with open('/etc/config.json') as fileId:
 #   config = json.load(fileId)

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['139.162.163.35']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'website.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'website.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'productionStatic')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

In my views.py a snippet of where I am importing the txt file in question is in static/aboutUsNytorv.txt. I have tried to change it to productionStatic/aboutUsNytorv.txt but it keeps saying that it cannot find the file.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

from django.contrib import messages
from django.views import View
from .forms import contactForm
from .forms import newsLetterForm

from website.Modules.emailMessage import sendEmail 
from website.Modules.registerEmailSubscription import registerEmail
from website.Modules.recaptchaValidate import Validate


# Create your views here.
class ContextBuilder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.context = {'imagePath' : None,
        'navbarLogoPath' : None,
        'links' : None,
        'menuImgPath' : None,
        'aboutUsImagePath' : None,
        'aboutUsText' : None,
        'dayRange1' : None,
        'timeRange1' : None,
        'form' : None,
        'emailSignUpForm' : None,
        'shopTitle' : None,
        'addressStreet' : None,
        'addressPhone' : None,
        'addressEmail' : 'kontakt@dimsum.dk',
        'addressCVR' : 'CVR: 38908901',
        'instagramLink' : None,
        'youtubeLink' : None,
        'facebookLink' : None}

    def Set_headerCoverImageLinks(self, linksList):
        '''
        Accepts a list of tuples containing ('Link_title', 'url')
        '''
        self.links = list()
        for linkTuple in linksList:
            self.links.append(linkTuple)

    def Set_context(self, **kwargs):
        '''
        The kwargs points to the dictionary keys in context, and the values are inserted
        '''
        for key in kwargs.keys():
            self.context[key] = kwargs[key]
    
    def importTextFile(self, filePath):
        with open(filePath,'r') as fid:
            self.textString = fid.read()


class indexPage(View):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.ContextObject = ContextBuilder()
        self.ContextObject.importTextFile('static/mainAboutUs.txt')
        
        self.ContextObject.Set_headerCoverImageLinks(linksList = [
            ('LOCATIONS', '#anchor_locations'),
            ('ABOUT US', '#anchor-aboutUs'),
            ('CONTACT', '#anchor-mainContact')
            ]
        )

        self.emailSignupForm = newsLetterForm()
        self.ContextObject.Set_context(
        links = self.ContextObject.links,
        imagePath = 'static/media/cover.jpg', 
        aboutUsImagePath = 'static/media/aboutus2900.jpg',
        aboutUsText = self.ContextObject.textString,
        coverTitle1 = 'We are dimsum!', 
        coverTitle2 = 'at',
        coverTitle3 = 'HIDDEN DIMSUM', 
        emailSignUpForm = self.emailSignupForm,
        shopTitle = 'Hidden Dimsum', 
        addressStreet = 'Nytorv 19', 
        addressPostcodeCity = '1450 København K',
        addressPhone = '+45-33 12 88 28')

        self.context = self.ContextObject.context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, template_name='index.html', context = self.context)
```

In my apache2 settings I have the below code where I have pointed the static alias to the folder in productionStatic. What have I missed?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

    Alias /static /home/jianwu/HD_website/website/productionStatic
    <Directory /home/jianwu/HD_website/website/productionStatic>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /media /home/jianwu/HD_website/website/media  
        <Directory /home/jianwu/HD_website/website/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>    

    <Directory /home/jianwu/HD_website/website/website>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>    
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jianwu/HD_website/website/website/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/jianwu/HD_website/website python-home=/home/jianwu/HD_website/website/env
    WSGIProcessGroup django_app
 
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Comment: Storing anything inside specific user `HOME` directory is not a good idea at all. `self.ContextObject.importTextFile('static/aboutUsNytorv.txt')` nope 1) use url reversing 2) why can't the client-side request this file via url by itself?

Comment: I am not storing the file in the user's home directory. The aboutUsNytorv.txt is just a text file with a long string. I am importing from the views.py and after reading in the long string, I am rendering out the page putting the string in a context. I have updated the views.py to make this clearer. With regard on url reversing, I guess that it is not an issue here since url was directing it to the correct class in my views.py

Comment: `/home/jianwu` ? `I am importing` in a wrong way. If you want to refer static files use url reversing. If they are not "normal" static files - build full paths. Word `static` is not being magically mapped from any part of code to either STATIC_ROOT or STATIC_URL.

Comment: you are right. After changing the path to absolute path solved the problem. I will look into reverse url. How can I make it magically mapped to the static folder? Is it because one need to use {% static %} syntax in the views.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is as commented by Ivan Starostin that one should give the absolute path in to the file in the production environment. Also using reverse url can also work in this case as suggested in the comment.